# Looking for a drop down navigation menu

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uinavigationitem

I am trying to make a drop down navigation menu for an iPhone client to my website. The menu type that I am searching for is the one used in Facebook's iPhone client. It is found in the upper left-hand corner of Facebook's application after you sign in. Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Unless you have a different Facebook iPhone app than I have, the menu triggered by the bar button item at the upper left doesn't drop down.  Instead the current view slides to the right to reveal a menu underneath it.  Is that the navigation menu you are talking about?

Comment: How is that done? It still appears to be some sort of list that comes from the header of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to an open source controller that implements a slide out like the facebook app.

http://ipup.github.com/PPRevealSideViewController

[slide out menu](http://ipup.github.com/PPRevealSideViewController)

There are a few other examples around in the community, but I've had luck with this one and hopefully you will too.

be well!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Man! I glanced over the documentation for this and it appears to be exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to try it out later on today. Would you say that PPRevealSideViewController is the best controller for the job or just most intuitive? Also, is this controller fully customizable- allows the editing of its background, editing of row cells?